# Does dropout regularization technique affect the test execution time in neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning

I've been asked a question in an interview exam about whether using dropout technique in neural network would affect the testing execution time if all the hardware are the same as not using dropout

Comment: At evaluation time, the dropout is not executed. This technique is applied only at training time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.